# undefined this in object function method express routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, object, methods

I'm new to express.
for routing I create an object in a file and export the object

```
import userController from "../controllers/userController.js"

// get all users
router.get("/", isAuth, isAdmin, userController.list)
```

the problem is, ***this** is undefined* on **userController**

```
const userController = {
  _statusCode: 200,

  async list( req, res ) {
    console.log(this);
    try {
      const users = await User.find()
      return res.status( this._statusCode ).json( respSC( users, this._statusCode ) )
    } catch( err ) {
      this.statusCode = 500
      return res.status( this._statusCode ).json( respER( this._statusCode, err ) )
    }
  }
}

export default userController
```

OR

```
const userController = {
  _statusCode: 200,

  list: async function( req, res ) {
    console.log(this);
    try {
      const users = await User.find()
      return res.status( this._statusCode ).json( respSC( users, this._statusCode ) )
    } catch( err ) {
      this.statusCode = 500
      return res.status( this._statusCode ).json( respER( this._statusCode, err ) )
    }
  }
}

export default userController
```

OR

```
const userController = {
  _statusCode: 200,

  list: async ( req, res ) => {
    console.log(this);
    try {
      const users = await User.find()
      return res.status( this._statusCode ).json( respSC( users, this._statusCode ) )
    } catch( err ) {
      this.statusCode = 500
      return res.status( this._statusCode ).json( respER( this._statusCode, err ) )
    }
  }
}

export default userController
```

in all three ways, the log is :

```
undefined
file:///C:/NodeJS/<project-folder>/app/controllers/userController.js:18
      return res.status( this._statusCode ).json( respER( this._statusCode, err ) )
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_statusCode')
    at list (file:///C:/NodeJS/<project-folder>/app/controllers/userController.js:18:31)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I know about objects and I try create object in chrome console and this is defined, but in routing of express, this is undefined.

can anybody explain why it's happen?

Comment: Why are you attempting to store `._statusCode` and `.statusCode` on the `userController` object at all?  That's going to be shared/overwritten by every single request.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you but this just an example for understanding `this`. I can't undestand why this is undefined!

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you so much, I know difference between real code and pseudo-code. I couldn't share my real code because of company polices. thank you for your answer and my problem solved with `bind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you pass `userController.list` in this:

```
router.get("/", isAuth, isAdmin, userController.list)
```

The JS interpreter reaches into the `userController` object and gets a reference to the `list` method and what it passes is just a reference to that method all by itself and will have no connection at all to the `userController` object at all.  **Thus, the `list()` method will just be called as a regular function by Express** (because it doesn't even know about the `userController` object and (if operating in `strict` mode), then calling a regular function leaves the `this` value as `undefined`.

So, that explains why what you observe is happening.

**Now, how to fix that.**  The simplest way would be use `.bind()`:

```
router.get("/", isAuth, isAdmin, userController.list.bind(userController));
```

This passes a dynamically generated stub function to Express and when Express calls that stub function and the stub function then calls your  `list` method in the right way to set the `this` value inside it to `userController`.

There are other ways to do this too:

- You could change the way the methods are declared so they will automatically bind to their parent object.
- You could write your own sub function that calls `list` as `userController.list()` and you pass your own stub function to Express.
- You can use utility functions in your class that auto-bind methods.
- There's even a new ECMAScript syntax proposal for a binding operator with `::`.

---

Here's a simple code example that shows both the `undefined` you're seeing and the solution. The first example `fn1` is what your current code is doing.  The second example `fn2` is my suggested solution.

```js
"use strict";

class MyObj {
    constructor() {
        this.greeting = "Hi";
    }
    getGreeting() { console.log(this); }
};

const obj = new MyObj();

// get a non-bound method and call it
const fn1 = obj.getGreeting;
fn1();

// get a bound method and call it
const fn2 = obj.getGreeting.bind(obj);
fn2();
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation, I understand now why `this` is undefined in my code.